# How can I see which layers my style is assigned to in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, layers, style, sld

How can I easily tell which layers in Geoserver (2.3.5 at the moment) are assigned a particular style?  For instance, I have a style called "buildings"... How can I tell which layers have a "Default Style" of 'buildings'?

The only way I've been able to find is to go in and click on "Remove Style", which will then pop up a box that says "if you delete this, these layers will be affected..."   But if I accidentally click OK instead of Cancel, bad things would happen... is there an easier/different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the GetCapabilities response from your server for each layer you will see a list of styles associated with it. The first named style is the default. So for simple queries I'd use the search function in my editor, or look at writing a script to parse the file into a dictionary of layer names and associated style names.

So for `topp:states` on my machine I get:

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
    <Name>topp:states</Name>
    <Title>USA Population</Title>
    <Abstract>This is some census data on the states.</Abstract>
    <KeywordList>
      <Keyword>census</Keyword>
      <Keyword>united</Keyword>
      <Keyword>boundaries</Keyword>
      <Keyword>state</Keyword>
      <Keyword>states</Keyword>
    </KeywordList>
    <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
    <LatLonBoundingBox minx="-134.731422" miny="24.955967" maxx="-66.969849" maxy="49.371735"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-134.731422" miny="24.955967" maxx="-66.969849" maxy="49.371735"/>
    <Style>
      <Name>population</Name>
      <Title>Population in the United States</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample filter that filters the United States into three
    categories of population, drawn in different colors</Abstract>
      <LegendURL width="81" height="80">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=topp%3Astates"/>
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
    <Style>
      <Name>polygon</Name>
      <Title>Default Polygon</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a polygon</Abstract>
      <LegendURL width="20" height="20">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=topp%3Astates&amp;style=polygon"/>
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
    <Style>
      <Name>pophatch</Name>
      <Title>Population in the United States</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample filter that filters the United States into three
    categories of population, drawn in different colors</Abstract>
      <LegendURL width="81" height="80">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=topp%3Astates&amp;style=pophatch"/>
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
    <Style>
      <Name>pop-places</Name>
      <Title>pop-places</Title>
      <LegendURL width="162" height="200">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=topp%3Astates&amp;style=pop-places"/>
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
    <Style>
      <Name>rotate-pophatch</Name>
      <Title>Population in the United States</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample filter that filters the United States into three
    categories of population, drawn in different colors</Abstract>
      <LegendURL width="84" height="80">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=topp%3Astates&amp;style=rotate-pophatch"/>
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
    <Style>
      <Name>pop_cartogram</Name>
      <Title>A value by alpha cartogram style</Title>
      <LegendURL width="20" height="20">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=topp%3Astates&amp;style=pop_cartogram"/>
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
  </Layer>
```

Comment: Thanks for this response... not quite as easy as I'd hoped, but with some python scripting/parsing, I should be able to write something to easily tell me what I want to know... will share the python code once I get it completed... Thanks again!